# mariadb сделать SELECT запрос с 2 массивами

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb, pymysql

На входе имеются 2 массива (id_users и id_tasks), эти два массива по индексно связаны между собой(т.е каждый пользователь с конкретной задачей). Мне необходимо составить SELECT запрос, чтобы база данных вернула записи c id_users = [2, 5]; id_tasks = [1, 4]

```
        id   id_users    id_tasks    information
----------  ----------  ----------   ----------
         1     2            1        Пользователь начал работать с задачей
         2     2            1        Пользователь закончил работать с задачей
         3     3            1        Пользователь начал работать с задачей
         4     4            4        Пользователь начал работать с задачей
         5     5            4        Пользователь начал работать с задачей
         6     5            4        Пользователь закончил работать с задачей
```

> ```
> query = f"""            
>     SELECT
>        `id_task`,
>        `id_users`,
>        `information`
>     FROM `name_db`
>     WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id_task`, '1, 4')
>     AND FIND_IN_SET(`id_users`, '2, 5')
>     """
> cursor.execute(query)
> cursor.fetchall()
> ```

Проблема в том, что данный запрос возвращает все записи с id_tasks 1 и 4, т.е в данном случае запрос вернет все записи находящиеся в таблице.

Comment: *данный запрос возвращает все записи с id_tasks 1 и 4* Неправда, вернётся только `task=1`. `task=4` не вернётся, потому что в списке у Вас не `'4'`, a `' 4'` - т.е. с ведущим пробелом, который является частью искомой строки. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=c6818c10bffb66c8062a1130ebf44752

Comment: ```WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id_task`, '1,4') AND (FIND_IN_SET(`id_task`, '1,4') = FIND_IN_SET(`id_users`, '2,5'))```.

Comment: @Akina, попробовал на небольших входных данных, запрос возвращает то что нужно, но как только подал большие массивы, мне в ответ приходят меньше половины данных, что я запросил. С чем это связано?

Comment: Чудес не бывает, сервер делает в точности то, что Вы просите. Если у Вас "нехватает данных", то либо данные такие, либо где-то в запросе накосячено (например, не учтено преобразование или переполнение типов, паразитные пробелы и пр.).

Comment: Но вообще правильный метод отбора такой: `WHERE (id_task, id_user) IN ((1,2), (4,5))` - он работает без преобразования типов и сразу проверяет пару значений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = f"""            
    SELECT
       `id_task`,
       `id_users`,
       `information`
    FROM `name_db`
    WHERE (`id_task`, `id_user`) IN ((1,2), (4,5))
    """
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.fetchall()
```